# SFDX CLI installation failing on OS X

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to install SFDX CLI on my macbook but it is failing and there are not enough details to see why it is failing.

I have gone through the system requirements and my machine matches those requirements and I have admin rights on the machine.

- CLI version: 6.34.0  -- Downloaded from official url (https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli)
- OS X version: 10.13.3

Log captured from Installer log:

```
Oct  5 16:04:22  installd[1742]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “sfdx-osx.pkg”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=./preinstall, NSURL=file://localhost/Users/javanoob/Downloads/sfdx-osx.pkg#sfdx-cli.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.salesforce.developer.cli, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “sfdx-osx.pkg”.} {
        NSFilePath = "./preinstall";
        NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201csfdx-osx.pkg\U201d.";
        NSURL = "file://localhost/Users/javanoob/Downloads/sfdx-osx.pkg#sfdx-cli.pkg";
        PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.salesforce.developer.cli";
    }
Oct  5 16:04:22  installd[1742]: PackageKit: Running idle tasks
Oct  5 16:04:22  Installer[2205]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “sfdx-osx.pkg”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=./preinstall, NSURL=file://localhost/Users/javanoob/Downloads/sfdx-osx.pkg#sfdx-cli.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.salesforce.developer.cli, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “sfdx-osx.pkg”.}
Oct  5 16:04:22  installd[1742]: PackageKit: Removing client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=2205, uid=850442940 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer)
Oct  5 16:04:22  Installer[2205]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
Oct  5 16:04:22  Installer[2205]: IFDInstallController 11B50 state = 8
Oct  5 16:04:22  Installer[2205]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
Oct  5 16:04:22  Installer[2205]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.
Oct  5 16:04:35  installd[1742]: PackageKit: Done with sandbox removals
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to update your npm ?

try this to update node =>

```
 npm i -g npm
```

than run the cli install again :

```
npm install sfdx-cli --global
```

Comment: Nowhere it says that node js should be installed but without it installation was failing. Once node installed, sfdx cli installation succeeded.